# Searching for a java based telegram api code

Tags: java, telegram

I fail to find a simple yet complete skeleton JAVA code of a telegram client using the Telegram API.
All I find is fractions of code, which are used by other code, or bot specific code which I don't need. 
All I want to do are simple things like login to my account, read my channels, etc.

For example, I found that I probably need to create the TelegramAPI object, but I cannot find any complete example of how to do that.

This is an example I found:

```
TelegramApi api = new TelegramApi(apiState, new AppInfo(apiKey, "bot", botName, botVersion, LANGUAGE_EN), new ApiCallback());
```

Your help is blessed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search provided telegram bot and telegram client api. I provide below the links.

**Telegram Client API**

https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi

https://core.telegram.org/api#tdlib-build-your-own-telegram

https://core.telegram.org/api/auth

**Telegram Bot API**

https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

https://monsterdeveloper.gitbooks.io/writing-telegram-bots-on-java/content/chapter1.html